# I can NOT submit the form

Tags: php, mysql

Hey guys
Im trying to develop an advance consumer website using php and I stuck somewhere while trying to get the data with submitting to another page. All I want to do is to get the checkbox values which are stored in an array and checked by user. I urgently need your help please here is the code:

```
$sql2="SELECT * FROM alinanfis WHERE alinanfis.fis_id='".$fis."'" ;
$resultFis=mysql_query($sql2);
if(mysql_num_rows($resultFis)>0)
{
    print "<form method='POST' action='deletionResult.php'>";
    print "<table>";
    print "<tr>";
    print "<th style='background: transparent;'></th>"; 
    print "<th>Fis No</th>";
    print "<th>isim</th>";
    print "<th>soyisim</th>";
    print "<th >Tarih</th>";
    print "<th>Fis Tipi</th>";
    print "<th>Nerede</th>";
    print "<th>Litre</th>";
    print "<th>Tutar</th>";
    print "</tr>";

    while($rowAlinan=mysql_fetch_array($resultFis))
    {
        $sqlFisTipi="SELECT * FROM atype WHERE a_id='".$rowAlinan['a_id']."'" ;

        $resultFisTipi=mysql_query($sqlFisTipi);
        $rowFisTipi=mysql_fetch_array($resultFisTipi);

        $sqlNerede="SELECT * FROM isyeri WHERE i_id='".$rowAlinan['nerde']."'" ;

        $resultNerede=mysql_query($sqlNerede);
        $rowNerede=mysql_fetch_array($resultNerede);

        $sqlMID="SELECT * FROM musteri WHERE m_id='".$rowAlinan['m_id']."'" ;

        $resultMID1=mysql_query($sqlMID);
        $rowMID1=mysql_fetch_array($resultMID1);

        print "<tr>";

        print "<td><input name='checkBox[]' type='checkbox' value='".$rowAlinan['fis_id']."' />

        php</td>";   

        print "<td>".$rowAlinan['fis_id']."</td>";
        print "<td>".$rowMID1['m_name']."</td>";
        print "<td>".$rowMID1['m_lastName']."</td>";
        print "<td>".$rowAlinan['alinan_tarih']."</td>";
        print "<td>".$rowFisTipi['a_name']."</td>";
        print "<td>".$rowNerede['i_name']."</td>";
        print "<td>".$rowAlinan['litre']."</td>";
        print "<td>".$rowAlinan['tutar']."</td>";
        print "</tr>";
    }

    print '<div class="form_settings">';
    print "<input class='submit' type='submit' name= 'send' value='Send'>";
   /
    print '</div>';
    print "</table>";
    print "</form>";
}//end of if(num_rows>0)

else
    echo '*no such receipt found!!';

mysql_close($con);
```

Here's the entire code: http://pastebin.com/SBiiSBHu .

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: What error(s) are you getting?

Comment: guys, when I click the submit button, it does nothing and redirects the page itself again, but I want it to submit the values to deletionResult.php page

Comment: What does the html in the browser look like?

Comment: Just to cover all your bases, you're certain deltionResult.php is in the same directory as this page?

Comment: @tkm256 no it is not. This code is in sorgula.php and I want the form in this oage to be submitted to deletionResult.php page

Answer (score 0):

You have not included all your code, but could it be that `$cols` is not set to `TRUE` in the top of the script?

**Edit:** I would really like to see the html generated by the php, but here are a few additional remarks:

1. You definitely need to clean / check your `$_GET["fname"]` variable before you feed it to a database
2. You need to specify a doctype

Apart from that, what kind of error do you have exactly?

Comment: @buri kuri: Where are you processing the `$_POST` data? **Edit:** Use a site like [Pastebin](http://www.pastebin.com) for more space.

Comment: its a 300 hundred line code, which means I cant put it here since there is not enough space for it but if you want to know, $cols is set to true in the top of the script

Comment: Im trying to process the values which are stored in the checkbox[] array(checkbox name also) and pass the array but submitting to deletionResult.php page

Comment: Ok here is the all details with the code. Im getting all data of the page that I used this code by another page using AJAX. so when I enter textboxes some data it appears with the appealed table with checkboxes on the left of each row. So I want to create a submit button to get the primary keys of that specific data checked and pass it into deletionResult.php page for to delete it by submitting. But the question is how can I make it work?

Comment: @buri kuri What does the html (not the php but it´s output) look like?

Comment: @jeroen the php and its output are same:http://localhost/OlyapBasla/admin.php (since Im running the code with wamp server, its localhost)

Comment: @buri, "its a 300 hundred line code" WHAT? 300 line code maybe.

Answer (score 0):

You may have problems because of the quirks with checkboxes,
they need the "checked" to work correctly,

```
<input type="checkbox" value="true" checked="checked" />
```

Besides that, use serialize($_POST) and you know what you've got.

regards,
//t

Comment: @user247245 the problem, there is nothing to do with checkbox right now, before that Im not even allowed to go to the deletionResult page after clicking submit button. In url section of the browser ,instead of deletionResult.php, same page's url is written, basically it does nothing.If I was able to redirect to the page desired with submit button, the data has to be passed through, I can easily figure out. Buyt the problem as I mentioned Im not even allowed to change the url by clicking the submit button